Tournament between 10 players, maximum number of games, also minimum number of wins to get 4th place
Say we have a video game tournament, in which 10 gamers play all against each other. Assume that each match ends in one person winning and another losing, no draws.

What is the maximum number of matches they can play?

Intuitively, this is just $\binom{10}{2} = 45$, no? I don't even know of a situation where this number can be more or less than 45, so maybe there exists some different tournament format besides round-robin where this number can be less than 45?

What is the minimum value of wins a gamer can have in order to be top 4?

My guess is that it's 5 wins? Let's say the top 4 players each win 5 games and lose 4. That makes for a total of 20 games won and 16 games lost. So among the remaining 6 players there needs to be a total of 25 games won and 29 games lost. But I don't know how to finish off the explicit construction/show that it's possible, any help would be appreciated.
EDIT: In response to Henry asking for clarification in his answer, if the top 4 players had the same number of wins and then the rest of the players had less wins each, then the top 4 players would count as top 4.
But let's say player 1 beats everyone, and then players 2, 3, 4, 5 had the same number of wins, with the rest of the players having even less wins each. Then I would say that players 2-5 are not top 4, they instead are tied for top 5.

For question 2, I am not clear whether you want the lowest number of wins where it is possible to come in the top $4$ or the lowest number of wins guaranteeing coming in the top $4$. I am also not clear if there is a tie-break rule when two players win the same number of matches.
For the low figure you might guess that the top three could beat the other players in every match. Among the remaining $7$ players there are ${7 \choose 2}=21$ games and they might each win $\frac{21}{7}=3$, coming jointly $4$th (or one of them coming $4$th using some tie-breaking rule). So $3$ wins could be the lowest possible number of wins for it to be possible to be in the top $4$ on this basis. If both of these fail to count as top $4$ then $4$ wins would be the lowest possible number of wins for it to be possible to be in the top $4$.
For the high figure, a similar argument might suggest it is possible for $5$ players to each win $\frac{5 \choose 2}5=2$ matches among themselves and each beat the other $5$ players, so winning $2+5=7$ matches in total.  If there is no tie-break rule then $7$ wins will guarantee being in the top $4$ even if the top $4$ turns out to be $5$ people, but with a tie-break rule this might not be sufficient (one could come $5$th) and $8$ wins would be needed for the guarantee. So $7$ or $8$ wins might be the answer on this basis.

With the edit to the question (player 1 beats everyone, and then players 2, 3, 4, 5 had the same number of wins, with the rest of the players having even less wins each. Then I would say that players 2-5 are not top 4), then it is possible to be in the top $4$ with just $4$ wins and it is guaranteed with $8$ wins.
Consider $9+8+7+4+3+3+3+3+3+2=45$ as a demonstration of possibility and $7+7+7+7+7+2+2+2+2+2=45$ as a demonstration of insufficiency.
Using the same interpretation, it is possible to be the top $1$ with $6$ wins but only guaranteed with $9$ wins; curiously the same can be said for the top $2$. It is possible to be in the top $3$ with $5$ wins but only guaranteed with $8$ wins.

Thanks Henry! I added some clarification in my original question on the nature of ties.

@Computers: I have added to my answer
